# JSON result being gained but script to add to page not working

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am using a JSON call to retrieve a list of available participant places based on a course code being passed in.  The idea is the result is then used to fill out a select which has been dynamically added to the page.  I am getting the response correctly but the code to add it to the page isn't working.

```
$("#venueCourses").live("change",function (event) {
    var cID = $("#venueCourses").val().split("|");

    -- This call works and provides a list of dates for the course passed in
    $.post("includes/ajaxdates.asp",{courseID:cID[0], lessonType:cID[1], retType:"dl"},function(result){
            -- The data is displayed correctly
            $("#cdisplay").html(result);
    });

    -- This is the JSON Call that retrieves data
    $.getJSON('includes/ajaxdates.asp',{courseID:cID[0], lessonType:cID[1], retType:"lt", ajax: 'true'}, function(data) {

        -- NOTHING IN HERE SEEMS TO WORK
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              items.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });

        $('<select/>', {
             'id': 'participantType',
             html: items.join('')
             }).appendTo('#partType');
    });
});
```

The JSON call gives this url to retrieve the response from
http://www.surreyjive.co.uk/includes/ajaxdates.asp?courseID=ES-1-2013&lessonType=Intermediates&retType=lt&ajax=true

And this is the JSON response
{'0':'Please Select','Lady':'Individual Lady','Couple':'Couple'}

The code that isn't working above actually used to be this body of code which didn't work either:

```
 var options = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
}
 alert(j);
 $("#participantType").html(options);
```

Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your response data, following script should work.

```
var response = ' {"values": {"option": [{"value": "0","text": "Please Select"},{"value": "lady","text": "Individual Lady"},{"value": "gent","text": "Individual Gent"},{"value": "couple","text": "Couple"}]}}';
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
var selectBox = $('<select/>', {'id': 'participantType'});
$.each(data.values.option, function(key, option) {
    $('<option />', {value: option.value, text: option.text}).appendTo(selectBox);
});
selectBox.appendTo('#partType');
```

Comment: Hi there that didn't seem to work at all.  I replaced the entire section with the code you provided and nothing seems to happen.  I even put an alert line in at the top of the callback function which would suggest that even though firefox is showing a JSON response it is not being classed as successful.  Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi Graham,
Did you check whether json response is valid or not? You can use this tool to check json response: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Hi mate, thanks very much for the advice.  I did check the JSON and it was not formatted correctly.  So I have rewritten the script that returns the JSON and the output now looks like this:

{"values": {"option": [{"value": "0","text": "Please Select"},{"value": "lady","text": "Individual Lady"},{"value": "gent","text": "Individual Gent"},{"value": "couple","text": "Couple"}]}}

Which formats correctly, the problem I know have is I cannot get to the data in the way the script amendment you supplied works.  Many thanks Graham

Comment: Hi Graham,
Considering your response, I have modified the code, please see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have to say I am confused now.  Your code works perfectly so my thoughts were just replace the string of JSON with the data from the callback function.  It still isn't working!  :-( I did put an alert in place to see what comes back and it shows an [OBJECT] not the string of data. I have added a JSON header to the asp file that is returning the JSON and the response parses as correctly formatted.  I really appreciate all your help so far, do you have any thoughts on this?  Many thanks Graham

Comment: Can you please paste the entire response object here?

Comment: {"values": {"option": [{"value": "0","text": "Please Select"},{"value": "lady","text": "Individual Lady"},{"value": "gent","text": "Individual Gent"},{"value": "couple","text": "Couple"}]}}

Comment: Hi Graham, if this is the case, my code is correct and should work correctly. Please check error console if there is any javascript error.

Comment: This is what firebug reports when I try to invoke the code.  TypeError: data is null - on this line of code $.each(data.values.option, function(key, option) {. When I alert the variable data, I get [object Object] but when I alert the response i get null.  The ASP page is clearly responding with the correct data, here http://www.surreyjive.co.uk/includes/ajaxdates.asp?courseID=E-1-2013&lessonType=Intermediates&retType=lt&ajax=true.  Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after looking at this problem with some fresh eyes I finally managed to fix the issue.  It is probably not the best way to fix it but does give me the results I wanted.  So the first change was to replace the method by which the JSON was returned.

FROM THIS:

```
$.getJSON('includes/ajaxdates.asp',{courseID:cID[0], lessonType:cID[1], retType:"lt", ajax: 'true'}, function(data) {
```

TO THIS:

```
$.get('includes/ajaxdates.asp',{courseID:cID[0], lessonType:cID[1], retType:"lt", ajax: 'false'}, function(d) {
```

So I replaced the $.getJSON to $.get so my ASP page returned a text string.

The text string was returned into the variable d from the callback function and so this was JSON parsed into the variable data.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(d);
```

Et Voila the script works every time.  I understand that MULTIDOT's code did work with a text string of JSON but not an object.  This is where my knowledge is really lacking and so it would be nice to understand where I was going wrong with the original script.

Many thanks to MULTIDOT for all his help.

Cheers
Graham